# Another method not allowing me to access HashMap values

Tags: java, netbeans, hashmap

I have implemented a hashmap in a method (call it method a) and in that method a I have called another method (call it method b) from which I transfer the hashmap built in method a to method b. Problem is that when I try to get the values of hmap in method b, it didn't allow me to write the statement for that.

In class analyzer I have 2 methods method a and method b. I have called a method b from the statement below:

```
analyzer v=new analyzer();
v.b(hMap1, 1);
```

In method b, I try to obtain the values of hmap1 but it does not allow me to write:

```
public HashMap b(HashMap x,int i)
{
  System.out.println( x.get("6").dstip);
}
```

It does not allow me to  write `.dstip` where as when I write this printing 
statement in method a, it gives the results on console. I have made the hashmap public, i dont know then why its not allowing me to write the desired statement.

Comment: Could you post a more complete code example? Is it just not printing, throwing an exception or not compiling?

Comment: when i write x.get("6").  and wait dstip to appear and it doesn't appear in the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HashMap is untyped, so invoking the `get` method on it returns instances of type `Object`. There is no public property on `Object` called `dstip`, so your compilation fails. Of course your code snippet would work if Java was dynamically typed, but thats totally off topic.

You should declare and pass around your `HashMap` with an appropriate parametized type. Say:

```
Map<MyDStipBean> map = new HashMap<MyDStipBean>();
public Map<MyDStipBean> b(Map<MyDStipBean> x,int i) {
    System.out.println( x.get("6").dstip);
}
```

On a side note, your Java code doesn't follow best practices for [naming](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) or [property access](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#177).

Comment: I would like to add that you should be using java.util.Map rather than java.util.HashMap in parameters.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini - very true. Good catch.